# Copy Table Storage with Azcopy

Tags: azure, azcopy

I want to copy Table Storage to another Account Storage and I know limitation about Azcopy doesn't support direct copy with Table Storage. I found [Copy table from azure to local storage using AzCopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35724147/copy-table-from-azure-to-local-storage-using-azcopy)
but it didn't work for me. I got error message `unknown command"/source:http..." for azcopy`, so I think that post is out updated.
So, I want to ask again. How to copy Table Storage to another Account Storage?
Thanks for your help

Comment: please install azcopy version 7.3, as per this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10#download-azcopy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For table storage, you should use Azcopy version 7.3. Please follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10#download-azcopy) to download/install version 7.3. Then you can use the command.

Comment: I just downloaded azcopy for linux version 10.22.2 and in help I do not see support for table storage.