# Using AzCopy for export table to blob storage in Linux

Tags: linux, backup, azure-table-storage, powershell-core, azcopy

I am writing a PowerShell core task in azure pipeline in order to backup my table storage using azcopy, from what I found only the version 7 of azcopy supports the table storage, my host is Linux and I can't find a command that works, I tried this but didn't work :

```
azcopy -source https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/tablename --destination https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/containername --source-key $input1 --dest-key $input2
```

Any idea how the command should be? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azcopy on linux does not support Azure table storage. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy-linux) and [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-azcopy-on-linux-preview/)

[image]
[image]

If you want to use the azcopy to export Azure table, we need to use the azopy V7 on windows. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#azcopy-with-table-support-v73)

Regarding how to do that, please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35724147/copy-table-from-azure-to-local-storage-using-azcopy)

For example

1. Install [Azcopy](https://aka.ms/downloadazcopynet)
2. Script

```
azcopy /Source:https://andyprivate.table.core.windows.net/log /Dest:https://andyprivate.blob.core.windows.net/copy/tablelog /SourceKey:<key> /DestKey:<key> /PayloadFormat:CSV
```

[image]
[image]

Besides, if your Azure table is very big, I suggest you use Azure data factory. Regarding how to do that, please refer to the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json) and the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-table-storage).

Comment: Thanks for the reply , yes I tried the version 7 of azcopy for windows, for testing on my local machine and didn't notice that linux version does not support table storage, but our build pipelines are on Linux at the moment .I will look into Azure Data Factory that you suggest.